# ブラウザ拡張でサイト内で実装されたJavaScriptを上書きしたい

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

#### 全体のやりたいこと

サイト内の通知でフィッシングサイトに遷移してしまうのを抑制するために、サイト内で通知が検知された場合はNotification apiを用いた通知のtitleとbodyの内容、遷移先のurlを取得して、ブラックリスト(.json)と照合して一致した際は通知の処理をオーバーライド、不一致の際はそのまま表示させたい。

#### 質問したいこと

サイト内でNotification API で実装されたものとブラウザ拡張がJavaScriptで同名のメソッドを定義したら後で定義したものに上書きされることは分かったのですが、サイト内で実装された方の title と body をブラウザ拡張で実装したNotificationで拾うことが出来ません。

#### 有識者とやり取りをする機会があったときに言っていたこと

・引数をコピーする必要はありません．元のメソッドに
　渡されるはずの引数は，同名のメソッド呼び出しにそのまま渡されます．
・あるWebページを読み込んだ際に，ブラウザ拡張が js を挿入し，
　挿入した js には Notification() が定義されています．
　そのWebページに Notification オブジェクトが作成された際には，
　挿入した Notification() が呼び出されるようになります．
・ですので，Webページのロードが完了した段階で Notification() が
　呼び出されると，挿入した方の Notification() が実行されます．
　その処理の中で，引数で渡された title と body を取得します．

サイト内で実装してあるnotification.js

```
  function showNotification() {
    const notify = new Notification("Hi there", {
      body: "通知のテストです。",
      icon: "assets/notifications.png"
    });

    notify.onclick = (e) => {
      //window.location.href = "https://github.com/"; //ページをリダイレクトさせる
      window.open('https://github.com/', '_blank');   //別タブで開く
    };
  }
```

ブラウザ拡張のcontent.js

```
Notification = (function(Notification) {
  console.log("point-0")
  function MyNotification(...args) {
    console.log("point-1")
    console.log("title: ", args[0]);
    console.log("body: ", args[1].body);
    console.log("icon: ", args[1].icon);
  };
  console.log("point-2")
  Object.assign(MyNotification, Notification);
  MyNotification.prototype = Notification.prototype;
  return MyNotification;
})(Notification);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Blocking phishing sites",
  "description": "Control method for web push notification by browser extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["js/content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

これで動かしたところconsole.logには何も表示されませんでした。

前述の通り、

> ・引数をコピーする必要はありません．元のメソッドに
> 　渡されるはずの引数は，同名のメソッド呼び出しにそのまま渡されます．

と言っていたのでnotification.jsのtitleやbodyの部分がcontent.jsのargs[0]とargs[1].bodyに渡されると思っていたのですが。
通知を一旦取得した後に、title,bodyとurlはブラックリストと比較したいのでどこかで変数に代入できればと思っています。（変数に代入しなくても比較できるならそれでも可）

お時間あるときにご回答いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 開発者ツールのコンソールで `Notification` が自作の物になっている事を確認しましたか？
なっていないなら、そもそもコードを挿入できていません。
なっているのなら、挿入のタイミングの問題かも知れません。

Comment: consoleを確認したところ、ブラウザ拡張の`Notification`は実行されているようです。
現在content.jsは質問のコードを実行しているのですが、`point-0`，`point-2`は出力されるのですが`point-1`が出力されませんでした。

Comment: 実行のタイミングはmanifest.json(v2)で`run_at`は初期値の`document_idle`なので問題ないと思われます

Comment: 念のためですが、コンソールで `new Notification("hello")` とすると、何が表示されますか？

Comment: title="hello"でその他がすべてnullまたはfalseのNotificationが実行されます。（通知も届きました）

Comment: Worker 内で Notification を作っている可能性もありますね。

Comment: コンソールで `new Notification` して `point-1` が表示されないのでしたら、そもそも `Notification` が自作の物に置き換えられていないと思います。

Comment: `print-1`が出力されないですね。`title`や`body`、`icon`のconsole.logも表示されていないので、content.jsの10，11行目から3行目の`function MyNotification(...args){ }`に入っていないのでしょうか？

Comment: manifest.jsonは(v2)で実装しているのですがWorkerの問題もあるのでしょうか...

Comment: すいません。最初に指摘しておくべきでしたが、もしコードが質問に書かれているだけならば、対象ページの `Notification` が置き換わることは無いはずです。
拡張のスクリプトと対象サイトのスクリプトは別環境で実行されますので、拡張側からスクリプトを挿入するコードを書いて実行する必要が有ります。
この挿入するコードはどこかに書いていますか？

Comment: ブラウザ拡張はmanifest.jsonとcontent.jsの2つで構成しています。manifest.jsonとcontent.jsの全コードを質問内に記載しました。同名のメソッド（Notification）を宣言した場合あとから宣言した方（content.jsのNotificationの中のMyNotification）が最終的に出力されると考えていました。

挿入するコードは特に記載していません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ブラウザ拡張のコンテンツスクリプトは「[Work in isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world)」ということで、グーバル変数などを共有していません。ですので、対象のページと同じ環境で動かすコードは何らかの手段で、対象のページに挿入する必要が有ります。

#### コードを挿入する処理の例

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-using-a-content-script

`js/content.js`:
このファイルに、対象のページに挿入したいコードが書かれているものとします。内容は省略。

`js/inject.js`:
コンテンツスクリプトとして実行され、対象のページに `js/content.js` を挿入します。下のコード例は実行のタイミング（`manifest.json` の `run_at` など）により、`html` 要素の直下に挿入されるダーティーな物です。`MutationObserver` などを使って洗練してもよいでしょう。

```js
console.log("-- inject script --");
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("js/content.js");
(document.head || document.documentElement).insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", script);
```

`manifest.json`:

マニフェストのバージョンが 2 の場合は `"web_accessible_resources": ["js/content.js"],` とします。

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Notify Wrapper",
    "description": "Replace the global variable `Notification` with a wrapper object.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["js/content.js"],
            "matches": ["https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*"]
        }
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://ja.stackoverflow.com/*"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "js": ["js/inject.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: mjyさん、有難うございます！無事今回質問したかったNotiricationのtitleとbodyの取得が出来ました！ここから遷移先urlの取得とブラックリストと比較に進めます。